# Angular app error and couldn't start with ng serve, npm install with many errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "airworkz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.8",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.8",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^1.15.4",
    "@firebase/logger": "^0.2.5",
    "@firebase/util": "^0.2.49",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.11",
    "@types/numeral": "0.0.28",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "compressorjs": "^1.0.7",
    "countries-list": "^2.5.5",
    "fibers": "^3.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^7.22.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.12.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^11.0.3",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^5.0.0",
    "node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^10.2.5",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "primeflex": "^1.1.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
    "primeng": "^11.1.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.3"
  }
}
```

version details

```
$ node -v
v12.14.1
$ npm -v
6.14.11

$ ng --version
Your global Angular CLI version (11.1.4) is greater than your local version (11.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.1.3
Node: 12.14.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.1.2
... common, core
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1101.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.1101.3
@angular-devkit/core                11.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics          11.1.3
@angular/animations                 11.0.8
@angular/cdk                        10.2.2
@angular/cli                        11.1.3
@angular/compiler                   11.0.8
@angular/compiler-cli               11.0.8
@angular/fire                       6.0.2
@angular/forms                      11.0.8
@angular/google-maps                10.1.0
@angular/platform-browser           11.0.8
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   11.0.8
@angular/router                     11.0.8
@schematics/angular                 11.1.3
@schematics/update                  0.1101.3
rxjs                                6.6.3
typescript                          4.0.3
```

and while i run

> ng serve --disable-host-check --sourceMap=false

i get following error

....

```
Warning: /home/weilies/apps/airworkz/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.es.js depends on 'raf'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /home/weilies/apps/airworkz/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.es.js depends on '@babel/runtime/regenerator'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/scrolling.js 1630:6-30
"export 'ɵɵstaticViewQuery' (imported as 'ɵngcc0') was not found in '@angular/core'



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names  |    Size
main.js             | main   | 0 bytes
styles.css          | styles | 0 bytes
vendor.js           | vendor | 0 bytes

Lazy Chunk Files    | Names  |    Size
xlsx.js             | xlsx   | 0 bytes

8 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-02-05T17:05:11.333Z - Hash: 70d1bef703fe4a626363 - Time: 5687ms

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/scrolling.js 1630:6-30
"export 'ɵɵstaticViewQuery' (imported as 'ɵngcc0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

What i have done was run a few npm install some packages, then it screwed the ng serve, then i decided to delete node_modules folder and let it rerun. Then i keep getting the error. I tried googled the error message but couldn't get something relevant. Please help as it's my one and only dev server. ;p

updates: i got bunch of error while running npm install
weilies@cloudshell:~/apps/airworkz$ npm install

```
> fibers@3.1.0 install /home/weilies/apps/airworkz/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

make: Entering directory '/home/weilies/apps/airworkz/node_modules/fibers/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
../src/fibers.cc:68:2: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘rand_r’?
  Handle<String> NewLatin1String(Isolate* isolate, const char* string) {
  ^~~~~~
  rand_r
../src/fibers.cc:72:2: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘rand_r’?
  Handle<String> NewLatin1Symbol(Isolate* isolate, const char* string) {
  ^~~~~~
  rand_r
../src/fibers.cc:94:2: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘rand_r’?
  Handle<Object> NewInstance(Isolate* isolate, Local<Function> fn, int argc, Local<Value> argv[]) {
  ^~~~~~
  rand_r
../src/fibers.cc:104:2: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘rand_r’?
  Handle<Number> ToNumber(Local<Value> value) {
  ^~~~~~
  rand_r
../src/fibers.cc:114:50: error: ‘Handle’ has not been declared
  Local<Value> GetStackTrace(TryCatch* try_catch, Handle<Context> context) {
                                                  ^~~~~~
../src/fibers.cc:114:56: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
  Local<Value> GetStackTrace(TryCatch* try_catch, Handle<Context> context) {
                                                        ^
../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> uni::GetStackTrace(uni::TryCatch*, int)’:
../src/fibers.cc:115:32: error: ‘context’ was not declared in this scope
   return try_catch->StackTrace(context).ToLocalChecked();
... and many more errors, then end with lines below...
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
sh: nodejs: command not found
npm WARN @angular/animations@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@11.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@11.0.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-webstorage@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-webstorage@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-webstorage@5.0.0 requires a peer of tslib@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! fibers@3.1.0 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/weilies/.npm/_logs/2021-02-06T00_45_14_687Z-debug.log
```

i have also upload the log file generated
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4m8oLZtxN60wAyfEyQ3TItrEQ55D266/view?usp=sharing

I tried few methods found in net, npm cache clean, then npm install --cache, but still goes back to same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Due to the node_modules deletion, you are not able to run the app.

Try to run in command line:

```
npm install
```

and then re-run the app:

```
ng serve -o
```

Comment: i have updated my topic with error while running npm install. not sure how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

(resolved) i end up create a blank new angular project, paste in the generic package.json file, then let each time run ng serve -o to let system highlight the missing module, build up one by one... it's painful but it works!